# Unable to add custom CSS files to my Bootstrap theme in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Twitter Bootstrap theme with WordPress for my site. My problem is that I want to make a custom navbar menu for my site and don't want to use the bootstrap default menu. Thats why I created a custom menu, but now my problem is that I don't know where to add my css files. I have added them into `wordpress/wp-content/themes/the-bootstrap/css/` but I don't know where or how to call them in `header.php` or in `function.php`.

There are already 2 CSS files in `wordpress/wp-content/themes/the-bootstrap/css` which are:

`bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`.

Here are my 4 css files which I want to include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mac.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/productbrowser.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call them in your `header.php` you will need to get the full url to the css file. You can use `get_template_directory_uri()` to do so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php get_template_directory_uri();?>/css/base.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php get_template_directory_uri();?>/css/mac.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php get_template_directory_uri();?>/css/nav.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php get_template_directory_uri();?>/css/productbrowser.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* put them in `header.php`, but that's technically wrong.

You should include them either in the theme functions or a custom plugin using the WordPress `wp_register_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` functions so that if any other sources uses these same files, they're only included once.

[wp_register_style() documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style)
[wp_enqueue_style() documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Here's an [example](http://markwilkinson.me/2011/02/loading-wordpress-scriptsstyles-correctly/).

Comment: thanks for ur answer..bt just want to know that how to add them in header.php file coz in my header.php fie there is only one stylsheet is called and that is:
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />

Comment: I don't think that's a stylesheet

Comment: sorry i was wrong....but there are no other stylsheet.please tell me that how can we caal them in header.php

Comment: Either include them using the functions listed in my answer (refer to the example for a how-to), or call to them like a normal external CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

In your header.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/the-bootstrap/css/base.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but can you combine any of those stylesheets into one file? Calling that many separate files slows down page load times.

Answer (score 0):

1- Put this in your template(yourtheme/something.php):

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

2- Go to yourmain css file (yourtheme/style.css) and put:

```
@import url('file/css/your 1st css file.css');
@import url('file/css/your 2nd css file.css'); 

body { 
padding-top: 60px; 
padding-bottom: 40px; 
     }
```

this will include any style.css you want.